# React Native [iOS] Database Options

Tags: database, sqlite, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I am looking to create an iOS app in React Native and wondering what's the best database option to fit my app.

The app will be supported by ~300 data objects which will be fetched as json objects from a remote server. There are some variances in attributes across these 300 objects. Therefore, I am hesitant to set up an inflexible database schema.

Ideally, I would just like 1 database with 2 attributes:
1) id (for example: from 1 to 300)
2) data (for example: {"hello" : "world"})

Give the above, any suggestions on what kind of react-native database module I should use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to my own experience in previous successful react-native project, you could use `AsyncStorage`, which is simple but yet powerful enough, you can store whatever you want!

Besides, you should also use `flux` or `redux`, which will provide you a **Store** solution where you can read & store the data related to `AsyncStorage` easily (*everywhere, on every page*)!

The steps are (*main flow's idea on how to organise your data and structure the logics*):

0/ **Importing libraries**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AsyncStorage,
  // ...
} from 'react-native';
```

1/ **Get data from your API** or somewhere (local files etc.), then write (save) the data to AsyncStorage:

```
async firstWriteFavorite() {
    fetch("YOUR_API_URL", {method: "GET", headers: {'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            try {
                // make sure you write a STRING into AsyncStorage, 
                // and also be careful which key of the JSON should be written, the below line is just a good example:
                await AsyncStorage.setItem("@PROJECT_NAME:your_favorite_array", JSON.stringify(responseJson.response));
                // if you use flux or redux here, you can perform some action here, then you can load the data everywhere later:
                // FavoriteActionCreators.set_favorite(responseJson.response);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
            }   
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error in first getting ajax data!", error);
        }
    );  

}
```

2/ **Retrieve the data from `AsyncStorage`**:

```
async loadFavorite() {
    try {
        var fav_array_string = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@PROJECT_NAME:your_favorite_array");
        // the above returned value is a STRING, then you can split it, or do whatever based on the structure you have written  
        var real_fav_id_array = fav_array_string.split('YOUR_SEPARATOR');
        // ...
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    } 
}
```

3/ *When you need to update the data*, firstly retrieve data, then bind the data to a variable and make changes to that variable, next **write the new data to `AsyncStorage`**:

```
async saveFavorite() {
    // loadFavorite() here, 
    // make sure you've got data "your_new_JSON_data" which has been converted into object, then maybe: "your_new_JSON_data.push({NEW_OBJ})";
    // after that, SAVE NEW DATA now:
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("@PROJECT_NAME:your_favorite_array", JSON.stringify(your_new_JSON_data));
        // same here, if you use flux or redux here, you can save the new data here:
        // FavoriteActionCreators.set_favorite(your_new_JSON_data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }   
}
```

The above code was copied and shortened from my real project's code, please try and tell me if you have any problem!

Comment: Have you made it work yet, if yes, please consider an up-vote, too, thanks ^^!